# Typescript expects undefined to be passed as argument

Tags: typescript, redux

**Typescript: 2.4.1**

I'm attempting to create a helper function to generate redux action creators.

What I've got:

```
interface IAction<T extends string, P = undefined> {
    type: T;
    payload: P;
}

function createAction<T extends string>(type: T): () => IAction<T, undefined>;
function createAction<T extends string = '', U = undefined, V = {}>(type: T, actionCreator: (payload: U) => V): (payload: U) => IAction<T, V>;
function createAction<T extends string>(type: T, actionCreator?: (payload?: any) => any) {
    return (payload: any) => ({
        payload,
        type,
    });
}

enum ActionType {
    INCREMENT = 'COUNTER/INCREMENT',
    DECREMENT = 'COUNTER/DECREMENT',
    ASYNC_INCREMENT = 'COUNTER/ASYNC_INCREMENT',
}

const increment = createAction(ActionType.INCREMENT, () => ({ amount: 1 }));
const incrementBy = createAction(ActionType.INCREMENT, (amount: number) => amount);
```

In this example, I expect `increment` to be a function that takes 0 arguments, and `incrementBy` to take exactly 1 (a `number`).

`incrementBy` works as expected, but Typescript throws this error when calling `increment()` (with no arguments):

```
[ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 0;
```

Trying to call it the same way I call `incrementBy`, e.g. `increment(42)`, I get this error:

```
[ts] Argument of type '42' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined';
```

This works: `increment(undefined)`.

**Is there a way to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply create another overload which says it'll return a function with no arguments, rather than a function which takes `undefined` as the only argument.

```
function createAction<T extends string>(type: T): () => IAction<T, undefined>;
function createAction<T extends string, V>(type: T, actionCreator: () => V): () => IAction<T, V>;
function createAction<T extends string, U, V>(type: T, actionCreator: (payload: U) => V): (payload: U) => IAction<T, V>;
function createAction<T extends string, U, V>(type: T, actionCreator?: (payload: U) => V): (payload: U) => IAction<T, V> {
    return (payload: any) => ({
        payload,
        type,
    });
}
```

However, your implementation doesn't seem to do anything with the function being passed. You likely want to do this:

```
function createAction<T extends string>(type: T): () => IAction<T, undefined>;
function createAction<T extends string, V>(type: T, actionCreator: () => V): () => IAction<T, V>;
function createAction<T extends string, U, V>(type: T, actionCreator: (payload: U) => V): (payload: U) => IAction<T, V>;
function createAction<T extends string, U, V>(type: T, actionCreator?: (payload: U) => V): (payload: U) => IAction<T, V> {
    if (actionCreator) {
        return (payload: U) => ({
            payload: actionCreator(payload),
            type,
        });
    } else {
        return () => ({
            payload: undefined,
            type
        });
    }
}
```