# Union type dispatch callback

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a universal function, which will be used to create callback actions.
But I'm not sure how to deal with union type in this case.
The function will receive a `type` and then callback will receive a `payload` if needed.
At the and function will return object with fields `type` and `payload` if payload needed.

**Interfaces that I declare:**

```
enum ActionTypes {
    CREATE_GAME = 'CREATE_GAME',
    GET_GAME_INFO = 'GET_GAME_INFO',
    PARTICIPANT_JOIN = 'PARTICIPANT_JOIN',
}

interface CreateGame {
    type: ActionTypes.CREATE_GAME;
}

interface GameInfoPayload {
    gameid: number,
    participants: [],
    phase: string,
    activated: boolean
}

interface GetGameInfo {
    type: ActionTypes.GET_GAME_INFO;
    payload: GameInfoPayload;
}

interface ParticipantJoin {
    type: ActionTypes.PARTICIPANT_JOIN;
    payload: boolean;
}

type GameAction = CreateGame |
                  GetGameInfo |
                  ParticipantJoin;

type PayloadGameAction = Extract<GameAction, {payload: unknown}>
```

**Callback that I'm trying to create:**

```
const buildAction = (action:ActionTypes) => {
    return (payload:PayloadGameAction['payload']):GameAction => {
        return {
            type: action,
            payload: payload
        }
    }
}

const createGame = buildAction(ActionTypes.CREATE_GAME);
const getGameInfo = buildAction(ActionTypes.GET_GAME_INFO);
const participantJoin = buildAction(ActionTypes.PARTICIPANT_JOIN);
```

The error that is produced at the end:

```
Type 'boolean | GameInfoPayload' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'GameInfoPayload' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Would be glad for any help.

Comment: Just as a heads up: we don't recommend that "union type" style any more since it is a *lot* of extra code for no good benefit. (see https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union) Please use the official Redux Toolkit instead which is the official recommendation to write *any* Redux code for over two years now and takes care about almost all TypeScript typings for you.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
enum ActionTypes {
    CREATE_GAME = 'CREATE_GAME',
    GET_GAME_INFO = 'GET_GAME_INFO',
    PARTICIPANT_JOIN = 'PARTICIPANT_JOIN',
}

interface GameInfoPayload {
    gameid: number,
    participants: [],
    phase: string,
    activated: boolean
}

interface CreateGame {
    type: ActionTypes.CREATE_GAME;
    // notice payload here
    payload: undefined
}

interface GetGameInfo {
    type: ActionTypes.GET_GAME_INFO;
    payload: GameInfoPayload;
}

interface ParticipantJoin {
    type: ActionTypes.PARTICIPANT_JOIN;
    payload: boolean;
}

type GameAction =
    | CreateGame
    | GetGameInfo
    | ParticipantJoin

type MathingGameActions<T extends ActionTypes> = Extract<GameAction, { type: T }>

const buildAction = <T extends ActionTypes = ActionTypes, K extends 
MathingGameActions<T> = MathingGameActions<T>>(action: T) =>
    (payload: K['payload']): K => {
        const result = {
            type: action
        }
        // prepare result here
        return result as unknown as K
    }

const createGame = buildAction(ActionTypes.CREATE_GAME)
const getGameInfo = buildAction(ActionTypes.GET_GAME_INFO)
const participantJoin = buildAction(ActionTypes.PARTICIPANT_JOIN)
```

Other option is [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads),
maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792179/typescript-expects-undefined-to-be-passed-as-argument) will be helpful

Comment: Thats great, thank's for the hint. I wonder could it be solved without adding `payload: undefined` to `CreateGame` interface?